# spark dataframe not appending to the table

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark

I am unable to append to a table when writing to a table using dataframe write

Here is the command I am using

```
 df1.write.mode("append").jdbc("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://noi-nipuna-w81/sams","sams", props)

This is the exception I get
java.sql.SQLException: There is already an object named 'sams' in the database.
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
```

Where am I making a mistake
I am using spark 1.4 version

Comment: can you try write().mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(tableName)

Comment: df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, "tablename", new Properties)

worked for me

Comment: I am not able to execute it with append. If I delete the table then it creates it with the data but does not append values to it . This gives me this error  There is already an object named 'sams' in the database.

Comment: looking at the dataframewriter code  "var tableExists = JdbcUtils.tableExists(conn, table)" always returns false event when table exists

Comment: Any update on this issue I am having the same problem here ...

Comment: I am not using apend now. I am running prepared statement using jdbc connector for sql server

Answer (score 2):

Urug and Hafiz have already answered. Below code did the job for me.

```
    sqlDF
        .write()
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .jdbc(jdbcDBUrl, "DBName.SchemaName.TableName", connProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MS SQL Server. I found that updating Spark to 1.6.0 fixed the problem ([link to the other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065782/how-to-write-into-microsoft-sql-server-table-even-if-table-exist-using-pyspark/35311980#35311980)). The reason was a buggy query for checking if the table exists.